# Read Spring Properties file from custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

We have written custom gradle plugin which we use in spring boot project, we are loading that plugin as classpath during buildscript and then applying that plugin in build.gradle of boot project.
my question is in gradle plugin we need to read properties file values of spring boot.
how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using it like below in my project.

**gradle.properties**

```
# public maven repo
publicMavenRepo=https\://www.xyz.com\:8443/repository/maven-public/

# publish maven repo
mavenRepoName=maven-snapshots
mavenRepoUrl=https\://www.xyz.com\:8443/repository

# git repo folder relative path
gitRepo=.
```

**build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url publicMavenRepo
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.ajoberstar.grgit:grgit-gradle:4.1.0"
    }
}

project.ext {
    mavenRepo="$mavenRepoUrl/$mavenRepoName/"

    grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: file("$gitRepo"))
    gitRevision = grgit.head().id
    gitBranch = grgit.branch.current.name
    gitAbbRevision = grgit.head().abbreviatedId
}
```

Comment: Is there a way like we inject values in java files using @value annotaion ?